# What are reasonable expectations for LVP floor installation?

Tags: installation

TLDR; What should a quality LVP floor installation feel like? Is it reasonable to have few barely noticeable soft spots? or should entire floor feel consistently solid through the entire area?

I had a CoreTec Plus LVP installed (7" x 48" vinyl planks) over a concrete subfloor. It is an interlocking floating floor. It was installed in place of glued down carpet.

Installer did remove the carpet and did scrape the floor. They did put thinset in one place. However there are few spots (including one where thinset was used) that feel soft, and I can see floor flexing as I step on it. Sound also changes as I walk on it. Most of the area feels rock solid though.

Installer claims that floating floor will always have soft spots, and that he has done a quality job per manufacturer's instructions and specifications.

My question is, before I go ahead and hire a certified floor inspector, how can I determine whether installation hasn't been done properly, or if I am being too picky about it?

Comment: LVP:  Luxury Vinyl Plank.  But then again, someone answering this question would probably know that.

Answer (score 1):

All floating floors are inevitably going to move a little when walked on, however any remaining thinset or glue residue or sheetrock mud clumps etc. should be scraped/ removed to an acceptable standard ( Coretec requires no "hump" exceeding 3/16" in a 10 foot radius)  failure to do so will result in excessive movement of the floor in the soft areas surrounding the hump.

Answer (score 0):

The LVP is softer, meaning not as stiff as other laminate flooring. But, he should have leveled the floor after he went through the scraping process. The only other possibility is that you walked on it too soon & he did use the thin-set as a leveler, but it wasn't dry & therefore you created a void with your body weight.

This can be corrected either way, but the floor would have to come back up to the area & re-leveled & dried before putting the floor back down. The LVP can extend the cure time of thin-set from a day to as much as a week, since the thin-set can't breathe.